# Jelastic - how to get the environment variables to a Docker container

Tags: jelastic

How do I get the [environment placeholders](https://docs.cloudscripting.com/creating-manifest/placeholders/#environment-placeholders) to show up inside a Docker container?

The documentation doesn't seem to be exactly clear where those can be used. I have tried to just set those inside the node env as shown in a JPS file that is added to this question.

For example, it shows the environment as `env-2461411` and its name as `Environment Test` in the [environment options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxL6L.png)

Once the environment is launched, the placeholders are still as they show in the JPS file, and not replaced by the actual values.

## Result

Placeholders don't seem to be replaced, and as such the shell doesn't like the environment it gets:

```
-bash: ${env.appid}: bad substitution
-bash: ${env.displayName}: bad substitution
-bash: ${env.domain}: bad substitution
-bash: ${env.envName}: bad substitution
-bash: ${env.name}: bad substitution
-bash: ${env.shortdomain}: bad substitution
-bash: ${env.url}: bad substitution
-bash: ${env.appid}: bad substitution
-bash: ${env.displayName}: bad substitution
-bash: ${env.domain}: bad substitution
-bash: ${env.envName}: bad substitution
-bash: ${env.name}: bad substitution
-bash: ${env.shortdomain}: bad substitution
-bash: ${env.url}: bad substitution
```

## Expected result

Environment variables showing in the bash environment, such as

```
env_domain=env-2461411
env_name=Environment Test
```

## Example JPS file

```javascript
{
    "jpsType": "install",
    "jpsVersion": "1.4",
    "name": "Environment Test",
    "description":
    {
        "text": "Template for testing environment variables test",
        "short": "Environment variables test"
    },
    "logo": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jelastic-jps/start-stop-scheduler/master/images/logo.png",
    "homepage": "https://jelastic.com/",
    "categories":
    [
        "apps/testing"
    ],
    "success":
    {
        "text": "## Environment test is up and running\nOpen the Jelastic SSH gateway and locate the test-node, see its environment with `env`"
    },
    "nodes":
    [
        {
            "image": "debian",
            "extip": false,
            "count": 1,
            "cloudlets": 16,
            "fixedCloudlets": 1,
            "nodeType": "docker",
            "nodeGroup": "test",
            "displayName": "test-node",
            "volumes":
            [
                "/root"
            ],
            "env":
            {
                "env_appid": "${env.appid}",
                "env_domain": "${env.domain}",
                "env_url": "${env.url}",
                "env_displayname": "${env.displayName}",
                "env_envname": "${env.envName}",
                "env_name": "${env.name}",
                "env_shortdomain": "${env.shortdomain}"
            }
        }
    ],
    "onInstall":
    {
        "log": "${placeholders}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the process of environment's creation mentioned placeholders are not initialized and can't be used. 
You can use the method [AddContainerEnvVars](https://docs.jelastic.com/api/#!/api/environment.Control-method-AddContainerEnvVars). 
In your case, it will be like [this](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=b56ba116d1e94ef194bc3bb620bf1d79).